# Kill process running as admin with python

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10, pid, administrator

I want to kill a process running as admin using Python. Is there a way how I can do this?
I'm using Windows 10.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've often found that it's easier to just use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) to wrap up a task that I know is easy from a command line into a few lines of python. This might be a bad idea for a high-stakes tool or server utility, but it's easy and effective.

Exactly how that's going to work for your situation will depend on how the python code in question is being used. Is it already running with *permissions* sufficient to kill the processes in question? Is it running from the command line where you can interact with it over stdin/stdout?

Also, I have limited experience doing this kind of stuff in Windows, but I understand it should still work.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! When I run it in IDE as a py it doesn't have the permission, but when I run it as an exe, I need to start the program as an administrator and so the exe has the permission. It's working only as exe.